# A question about matrix manipulation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, indexing, matrix

Given a 1*N matrix or an array, how do I find the first 4 elements which have the same value and then store the index for those elements?

PS:
I'm just curious. What if we want to find the first 4 elements whose value differences are within a certain range, say below 2? For example, M=[10,15,14.5,9,15.1,8.5,15.5,9.5], the elements I'm looking for will be 15,14.5,15.1,15.5  and the indices will be 2,3,5,7.

Comment: what do u mean by first 4 elements which have the value?
...and what exactly do u mean by index?

Comment: Hi Mulki. Thanks for pointing that out. I modified the question again.

Comment: I don't understand the question. maybe my english isn't enough for it. What does it mean "store the index for those elements" ? we should return the index ?

Comment: what did u change?
I am still unable to understand you question...Can you please add in details...

Comment: The example in your recent edit is confusing. Shouldn't 4 be the first value that is repeated 4 times, not 5?

Comment: Ya, you are right, gnovice. The answers given by the people below were posted before I made my last editing which is quite confusing. I will delete it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the first value present 4 times in the array 'tab' in Matlab, you can use

```
num_min = 4
val=NaN;
for i = tab
    if sum(tab==i) >= num_min
        val = i;
        break
    end
end
ind = find(tab==val, num_min);
```

By instance with

```
tab = [2 4 4 5 4 6 4 5 5 4 6 9 5 5]
```

you get

```
val =
     4
ind =
     2     3     5     7
```

Comment: You should write the `sum` statements as : `if sum(tab==i)>=num_min`. Currently it sums up the values, so if the first element of the array is 9, which appears only once, it'll be picked.

Comment: Also, you should set `val` to `NaN` before starting the loop - if there is no value that is repeated at least 4 times, you get an error in the last line because `val` won't be defined.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The algorithm you used is clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my MATLAB solution:

```
array = randi(5, [1 10]);            %# random array of integers

n = unique(array)';                  %'# unique elements
[r,~] = find(cumsum(bsxfun(@eq,array,n),2) == 4, 1, 'first');
if isempty(r)
    val = []; ind = [];              %# no answer
else
    val = n(r);                      %# the value found
    ind = find(array == val, 4);     %# indices of elements corresponding to val
end
```

Example:

```
array =
     1     5     3     3     1     5     4     2     3     3
val =
     3
ind =
     3     4     9    10
```

---

#### Explanation:

First of all, we extract the list of unique elements. In the example used above, we have:

```
n =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

Then using the BSXFUN function, we compare each unique value against the entire vector array we have. This is equivalent to the following:

```
result = zeros(length(n),length(array));
for i=1:length(n)
    result(i,:) = (array == n(i));        %# row-by-row
end
```

Continuing with the same example we get:

```
result =
     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

Next we call CUMSUM on the `result` matrix to compute the cumulative sum along the rows. Each row will give us how many times the element in question appeared so far:

```
>> cumsum(result,2)
ans =
     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
     0     0     1     2     2     2     2     2     3     4
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2
```

Then we compare that against four `cumsum(result,2)==4` (since we want the location where an element appeared for the forth time):

```
>> cumsum(result,2)==4
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Finally we call FIND to look for the first appearing `1` according to a column-wise order: if we traverse the matrix from the previous step column-by-column, then the row of the first appearing `1` indicates the index of the element we are looking for. In this case, it was the third row (`r=3`), thus the third element in the unique vector is the answer `val = n(r)`. Note that if we had multiple elements repeated 4 times or more in the original array, then the one first appearing for the forth time will show up first as a `1` going column-by-column in the above expression.

Finding the indices of the corresponding answer value is a simple call to FIND...

Comment: Nice! First loopless solution with nice use of bsxfun. Good stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your code, Amro! But I can give only one tick for this question. Although I'm a newbie in Matlab and not really able to understand the magic of bsxfun, from other people's comments I can see it's a pretty good algorithm. So thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining all these! It's much clearer to me now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is C++ code

```
std::map<int,std::vector<int> > dict;

std::vector<int> ans(4);//here we will store indexes
bool noanswer=true;

//my_vector is a vector, which we must analize
for(int i=0;i<my_vector.size();++i)
{
    std::vector<int> &temp = dict[my_vector[i]];
    temp.push_back(i);
    if(temp.size()==4)//we find ans
    {
         std::copy(temp.begin(),temp.end(),ans.begin() );
         noanswer = false;
         break;
    }   
}
if(noanswer)
   std::cout<<"No Answer!"<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Ashot Martirosyan!

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this and use Amro's mighty solution . . .

Here is how I'd do it in Matlab. The matrix can be any size and contain any range of values and this should work. This solution will automatically find a value and then the indicies of the first 4 elements without being fed the search value a priori.

```
tab = [2 5 4 5 4 6 4 5 5 4 6 9 5 5]

%this is a loop to find the indicies of groups of 4 identical elements
tot = zeros(size(tab));
for nn = 1:numel(tab)
    idxs=find(tab == tab(nn), 4, 'first');
    if numel(idxs)<4
        tot(nn) = Inf;
    else
        tot(nn) = sum(idxs);
    end        
end

%find the first 4 identical
bestTot = find(tot == min(tot), 1, 'first' );

%store the indicies you are interested in.
indiciesOfInterst = find(tab == tab(bestTot), 4, 'first')
```

Comment: A few comments: You can use `randi` to generate a list of random integers. Also, when you count how many repetitions there are, you're currently summing up indices, not counts, and you're summing them up even if there's less than four, so you're unlikely to get the right result.

Comment: Was just fixing the *less than 4* issue after testing clement's revised code and then realising my solution was broken too. Cheers for the headsup about randi. With the revisions, clement's solution > mine.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't easily understand some of the solutions, I made that one:

```
l = 10; m = 5; array = randi(m, [1 l])

A = zeros(l,m);    % m is the maximum value (may) in array
A(sub2ind([l,m],1:l,array)) = 1;
s = sum(A,1);
b = find(s(array) == 4,1); 
% now in b is the index of the first element

if (~isempty(b)) 
    find(array == array(b))
else 
    disp('nothing found'); 
end
```

I find this easier to visualize. It fills '1' in all places of a square matrix, where values in array exist - according to their position (row) and value (column). This is than summed up easily and mapped to the original array. Drawback: if array contains very large values, A may get relative large too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, user492238!

Answer (score 0):

You're PS question is more complicated. I didn't have time to check each case but the idea is here :

```
M=[10,15,14.5,9,15.1,8.5,15.5,9.5]
val = NaN;
num_min = 4;
delta = 2;
[Ms, iMs] = sort(M);
dMs = diff(Ms);
ind_min=Inf;
n = 0;
for i = 1:length(dMs)
    if dMs(i) <= delta
    n=n+1;
    else
    n=0;
    end
    if n == (num_min-1)
        if (iMs(i) < ind_min)
            ind_min = iMs(i);
        end
    end
end
ind = sort(iMs(ind_min + (0:num_min-1)))
val = M(ind)
```

Comment: Hi Clement. Thanks for your solution! But could you explain further about this part-- if(iMs(i)<ind_min)  ind_min=iMs(i);  ? I couldn't understand the meaning behind. Thank you very much!

Comment: In iMs (index of sorted M), the index aren't strictly ascending (but the corresponding values are). In consequence, when you find 4 elements in the interval, you must check if their original index is the smallest beyond the groups of 4 acceptable values.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Clement! Now I understand.